# Weird glitching out Pygame Python images

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have no idea why when the button is pressed it doesnt just go to the next function. It goes back to the other one its really weird and annoying.
It should go to the whattodo function but it does for like half a second then goes to the other. Anyone know why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,700))
pygame.display.set_caption("Anti-Docter")
titlescreen = pygame.image.load('titleframe.bmp')
boxinfo = pygame.image.load('boxinfo.bmp')
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
randommommycolor = (255,139,12)
Brown = (102,51,0)
Lighter_Brown = (120,59,5)
def mts(text, textcolor, x, y, fs):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None,fs)
    text = font.render(text, True, textcolor)
    screen.blit(text, [x,y])
def buttonPlay(x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1:
            whattodo()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic,(x,y,w,h))
def whattodo():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    screen.blit(boxinfo, (0,0))
    pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    screen.blit(titlescreen, (0,0))
    buttonPlay(580, 350, 200, 90, Brown, Lighter_Brown)
    mts("Play", black, 620, 365, 80)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time your main loop repeats, it calls 'buttonPlay'. There is nothing inside 'whattodo' that changes this behaviour, so 'whattodo' runs once then control flow passes back to the main loop, which just repeats 'buttonPlay'.